# Internal error while accessing GIT repository from RSA 9.1 using TFS plug-in

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, team-explorer-everywhere

I am able to connect to GIT server from RSA 9.1 using the TFS plugin.However, while accessing the Git repositories, I am getting the following internal error:

> An internal error occurred during: "Loading section 'All
>   Repositories'". org/eclipse/egit/core/Activator "

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: Team Explorer EveryWhere doesn't use its own Git client, it depends on e-git.

Comment: @jessehouwing thank you - fixed it for me - you should move comment to answer :) e-git installation here: http://www.eclipse.org/egit/download/

Answer (score 0):

You can get a local clone of the remote repository and then import the repository
[image]

Or you can host your remote repository in TFS, then manually configured in EGit. Once this connection is established, you can use the EGit tools to perform basically any Git function, like committing, pushing, and creating new branches. 
Details refer the 'Integration with Eclipse EGit tools' in [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2013/11/03/team-explorer-everywhere-2013-is-available/).

And you can [download egit from here](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/download/).